# Swift how can I check if I iterate through the last item of List[String]

Tags: ios, swift

i need to check when i iterated through the last item. I cannot just put the line after my for loop because then i receive always an empty list. I tried the following but this one doesnt work:

```
.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
    if snapshot.exists() {
        for rest in snapshot.children.allObjects.count as! [DataSnapshot] {
            let refi = Database.database().reference().child("Users")
            refi.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshoti) in
                if snapshoti.value as! String == "active"{
                    let userid = rest.key
                    self.someProtocol[rest.key] = self.checksum

                    if self.checksum == self.someProtocol.count-1 {
                        self.sortUsers()
                    } else {
                       
                    }
                    self.checksum = self.checksum+1
                }
            })
        }
    }
```

Comment: use enumerate for iteration and from that you can check index == array.lastIndex

Comment: The line `snapshot.children.allObjects.count as! [DataSnapshot]` looks suspicious: is `count` really returning an array or `DataSnapshot`?

Comment: @PravinTate could you describe it more in detail.

Comment: @dr_barto sorry i changed this line into snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot] but doesnt work

Comment: Are you getting a compiler error, a runtime error, or is the code just not doing what you want it to do? Please be more specific and post error messages.

Comment: it just dont do what i want

Comment: i just need to know when the last item of the snapshot.children loop is reached

Answer (score 48, accepted):

The answer of dr_barto will work but needs the following adaptation:

```
for (idx, element) in array.enumerated() {
  if idx == array.endIndex-1 {
    // handling the last element
  }
}
```

From the Apple documentation:

> endIndex is the array’s “past the end” position—that is, the position one greater than the last valid subscript argument

Answer (score 17):

If you don't want to use index, you can check element like this:

```
for element in array {
    if element == array.first {
        print("first")
    } else if element == array.last {
        print("last")
    }
}
```

Comment: This works if you know each element in the array will be unique. If there is a chance of duplicate values, then you should use the index approach.

Answer (score 3):

**EDIT** my answer won't work since (as pointed out in the comments) `endIndex` is never going to match any index value returned from `enumerated` because it denotes the *index after the last element*. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/53341276/5471218 for how it's done correctly :)

---

As pointed out in the comments, you should use `enumerated`; given an `array`, you'd use it like this:

```
for (idx, element) in array.enumerated() {
  if idx == array.endIndex {
    // handling the last element
  }
}
```

Comment: but how can i use it while iterating through my Datasnapshot?

Comment: Just set `array` to your list-of-whatever; in your case this might be `snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot]`.

Comment: but for snapshot i cannot add enumerated()

Comment: `let array = snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot]`, then you can call `array.enumerated`

Comment: Datasnapshot has no member lastIndex

Comment: You are right, sorry :) c&p error from the other comment, it's `endIndex`; I'll update the example accordingly.

Comment: What's not working? I updated the example code, have you tried it in your code?

Comment: In your example, `idx` can never be equals to `endIndex` since `endIndex` is the index following the last index of a collection. `endIndex` is analogous to the amount of items in a collection.

Comment: @MatiasPequeno right, has been corrected here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53341276/5471218

Answer (score 3):

Could be made into an extension also:

```
extension Array {
    func lastIndex(index: Int) -> Bool {
        index == endIndex-1
    }
}
```

or

```
extension Array where Element : Equatable {
    func isLast(element: Element) -> Bool {
        last == element
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

for the newbies in swift like me..
I attached the full code.

```
      ref.child("BookShelf").child(userID!).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
        if let datasnap = snapshot.value as? Dictionary<String, Any> {
            for (index,data) in datasnap.enumerated() {
                let book = Book(userid: data.key , dataSnap: data.value as! Dictionary<String, Any>)
                bookShelf.append(book)

                print("index",index)
                print("datasnap.count-1",datasnap.count-1)
                if(index == datasnap.count-1){
                    print("1 bookshelf count getFirebaseData()",bookShelf.count)
                    self.showDashBoard(bookShelf: bookShelf)
                }
            }
            
            //if last data then trigger show
        }
     
    }) { (error) in
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this solution

```
.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
        if snapshot.exists(){

            for (index,rest) in snapshot.children.allObjects {
                    if index == (snapshot.children.allObjects.count - 1){
                       //yeah finally you are getting the last object :)
                      }
                    }

                })

            }
```

P.S: I Assume snapshot.children.allObjects is an array of [DataSnapshot]